# El programa funciona mal si cambio el orden de ejecución de los botones java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con los botones de mi programa java, el programa es una acción para prender un avion con tres pasos= boton1 luego el boton2 y tercero el 3, anda excelente si lo empezás de izquierda a derecha, pero si te salteás algun número hay cosas que dejan de aparecer, por lo que entiendo el problema está en los if con los setVisible(false), setVisible(true), pero mi problema es que no sé como arreglarlo, intuyo que hay que crear objetos y métodos pero ando flojo en eso.

```
package Vista;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import Controlador.Aviso_despegue;
import Modelo.Avion;

public class VentanaJuego1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JPanel panelinstrumentos, panelbotones, panelluces, panelluces1, panelluces2, panelluces3, panelenunciados, paneldeinstrumentosdividido;
    public JButton botonfuel, botonelectrico, botonstart, botonsiguiente;
    public JLabel labelfuel, labelelectrico, labelstart, labelenunciado1, labelenunciado2, labelenunciado3, labeltodoapagado1, labeltodoencendido1, labelimgon1, labelimgon2, labelimgon3, labelimgoff1, labelimgoff2, labelimgoff3, labelfuelon, labelelectricoon, labelstarton, labelsolomasterfuel, labelsoloepu, labelsolostart, labelpordespegar;
    public ImageIcon todoapagado1, todoencendido1, imgon1, imgon2, imgon3, imgoff1, imgoff2, imgoff3, imgelectricidad, solomasterfuel, soloepu, solostart, pordespegar;
    public JCheckBox chk1, chk2, chk3;
    public JTextArea panelderespuesta;



    public VentanaJuego1() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelinstrumentos = new JPanel();
        panelbotones = new JPanel();
        panelluces = new JPanel();
        panelluces1 = new JPanel();
        panelluces2 = new JPanel();
        panelluces3 = new JPanel();
        panelenunciados = new JPanel();

        paneldeinstrumentosdividido = new JPanel();
        botonfuel = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/nafta.png"));
        botonelectrico = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/electricidad.png"));
        botonstart = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/fuego.png"));
        botonsiguiente = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/flechaverde.png"));
        todoapagado1 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/todoapagado11.jpg");
        labeltodoapagado1 = new JLabel(todoapagado1);
        todoencendido1 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/todoencendido.jpg");
        labeltodoencendido1 = new JLabel(todoencendido1);
        imgon1 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/onverde.png");
        labelimgon1 = new JLabel(imgon1);
        imgon2 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/onverde.png");
        labelimgon2 = new JLabel(imgon2);
        imgon3 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/onverde.png");
        labelimgon3 = new JLabel(imgon3);
        imgoff1 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/offrojo.png");
        labelimgoff1 = new JLabel(imgoff1);
        imgoff2 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/offrojo.png");
        labelimgoff2 = new JLabel(imgoff2);
        imgoff3 = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/offrojo.png");
        solomasterfuel = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/solomasterfuel.jpg");
        labelsolomasterfuel = new JLabel(solomasterfuel);
        soloepu = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/soloepu.jpg");
        labelsoloepu = new JLabel(soloepu);
        solostart = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/solostart.jpg");
        labelsolostart = new JLabel(solostart);
        pordespegar = new ImageIcon("../Juego_avion/src/Vista/f16despegar.jpg");
        labelpordespegar = new JLabel(pordespegar);
        panelderespuesta = new JTextArea(16, 20);
        panelderespuesta.setEditable(false);
        panelderespuesta.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panelderespuesta.setForeground(Color.green);



        labelimgoff3 = new JLabel(imgoff3);
        labelfuel = new JLabel("Combustible");
        labelelectrico = new JLabel("E.P.U");
        labelstart = new JLabel("Ignición");
        labelelectricoon = new JLabel("Paso de Corriente");
        labelfuelon = new JLabel("Paso de combustible");
        labelstarton = new JLabel("Ignición de combustible");
        labelenunciado1 = new JLabel("1) Primero tenemos que darle corriente prendiendo la E.P.U.");
        labelenunciado2 = new JLabel("2) Abra el paso de combustible a la turbina.");
        labelenunciado3 = new JLabel("3)Haga ignición.");





        this.add(panelinstrumentos, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelinstrumentos.add(labeltodoapagado1);

        this.add(panelluces, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        panelluces.add(panelluces1, new GridLayout(3, 5));
        panelluces.add(panelluces2, new GridLayout(3, 5));
        panelluces.add(panelluces3, new GridLayout(3, 5));

        panelluces1.add(labelimgoff1);
        panelluces1.add(labelelectrico);
        panelluces2.add(labelimgoff2);
        panelluces2.add(labelfuel);
        panelluces3.add(labelimgoff3);
        panelluces3.add(labelstart);


        panelluces.add(panelenunciados, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelenunciados.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5));
        panelenunciados.add(labelenunciado1);
        panelenunciados.add(labelenunciado2);
        panelenunciados.add(labelenunciado3);



        this.add(panelbotones, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panelbotones.add(botonelectrico);
        botonelectrico.setText("E.P.U");

        panelbotones.add(botonfuel);
        botonfuel.setText("Fuel Maestro");


        panelbotones.add(botonstart);
        botonstart.setText("Ignición");


        panelbotones.add(botonsiguiente);
        botonsiguiente.setText("Siguiente");



        botonelectrico.addActionListener(this);
        botonfuel.addActionListener(this);
        botonstart.addActionListener(this);
        botonsiguiente.addActionListener(this);




    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object obj1 = e.getSource();
        if (obj1.equals(botonelectrico)) {
            labeltodoapagado1.setVisible(false);


            panelinstrumentos.add(paneldeinstrumentosdividido);
            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.add(labelsoloepu, BorderLayout.WEST);
            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.add(panelderespuesta, BorderLayout.EAST);
            panelderespuesta.append("- Electricidad activado -.\n");
            labelimgoff1.setVisible(false);
            panelluces1.add(labelimgon1);
            labelimgon1.setVisible(true);
            labelelectrico.setVisible(false);
            panelluces1.add(labelelectricoon);
            labelelectricoon.setVisible(true);

            Avion encendido;
            encendido = new Avion();
            encendido.encender_Ups();

            labelenunciado1.setVisible(false);


        }
        Object obj2 = e.getSource();
        if (obj2.equals(botonfuel)) {
            labeltodoapagado1.setVisible(false);
            labelsoloepu.setVisible(false);


            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.add(labelsolomasterfuel);

            panelderespuesta.append("- Fuel activado -.\n");


            labelimgoff2.setVisible(false);
            panelluces2.add(labelimgon2);
            labelimgon2.setVisible(true);
            labelfuel.setVisible(false);
            panelluces2.add(labelfuelon);
            labelfuelon.setVisible(true);

            Avion encendido;
            encendido = new Avion();
            encendido.encender_Combustible();

            labelenunciado2.setVisible(false);
        }
        Object obj3 = e.getSource();
        if (obj3.equals(botonstart)) {
            labeltodoapagado1.setVisible(false);
            labelsoloepu.setVisible(false);
            labelsolomasterfuel.setVisible(false);

            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.add(labelsolostart);
            panelderespuesta.append("- Start activado -.\n\n\n*   Turbina prendida   *");

            labelimgoff3.setVisible(false);
            panelluces3.add(labelimgon3);
            labelimgon3.setVisible(true);
            labelstart.setVisible(false);
            panelluces3.add(labelstarton);
            labelstarton.setVisible(true);

            Avion encendido;
            encendido = new Avion();
            encendido.encender_Turbinas();
            labelenunciado3.setVisible(false);

            Avion sonidoencendido;
            sonidoencendido = new Avion();
            sonidoencendido.turbinas_Encendidas();




        }

        Object obj4 = e.getSource();
        if (obj4.equals(botonsiguiente)) {
            labeltodoapagado1.setVisible(false);
            labelsoloepu.setVisible(false);
            labelsolomasterfuel.setVisible(false);
            labelsolostart.setVisible(false);
            paneldeinstrumentosdividido.setVisible(false);
            panelinstrumentos.add(labelpordespegar);


            Aviso_despegue aviso;
            aviso = new Aviso_despegue();
            aviso.actionPerformed(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes contarnos que hace el boton1, boton2 y boton 3?

Comment: El botonepu cambia a otra imagen y agrega un JTextarea, El botonfuel cambia a otra imagen y agrega un datos al JTextarea ya creada, y El botonstart hace lo mismo que el anterior, si lo ejecuto en ese orden anda excelente, cuando les cambio el orden en que toco los botones, se me desorganiza todo, imagenes que  no aparecen, las areas de teto tampoco. etc

Comment: Debe ser porque cuando das clicknennel boton 1 habilitas que se vea la imagen y los otros campos que cada boton muestra, deberias validar que si los elementos del primer paso nonestan visibles, no muestres los demas y advierts que el pso 1 es primero

Comment: Estoy intentando con los if haber que pasa

Comment: yo estoy haciendo esta comparación y no me la toma,   if ((etiqueta.equals(botonfuel)&&etiqueta.equals(botonelectrico))) {  }

Comment: Por ultimo, me puedes dar el orden de los botones y quye hace cada uno? Por ejemplo otonfuel, botonelectrico, botonstart, botonsiguiente;, cual seria el orden logico y correcto?

Comment: 1) botonelectrico / 2) botonfuel / 3) botonstart / 4) botonsiguiente  /  este último lo usaría para cambiar de JPanel, pero si no soluciono lo anterior no puedo seguir. puedo enviar todo el proyecto si es necesario sin problemas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47591/discussion-between-sioesi-and-berlot83).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No voy a escribir todo tu código ya que es extenso, pero ¿Por que no darle a cada botón un evento Click? y por otro lado, Si tu flujo debe ser siempre igual porque no impedir que el usuario de click en otros botones si no ha hecho el paso anterior... Me explico

Tu orden es :

- Botón eléctrico
- Botón Fuel
- Botón Start
- Botón Siguiente

Por ende.. el único botón disponible para hacer click en primera instancia es Botón Eléctrico... Luego de hacer todo el tratamiento de este primer click, habilitamos el segundo botón, Boton Fuel y así sucesivamente con los demás botones.

Algo asi :

```
panelbotones.add(botonelectrico);
botonelectrico.setText("E.P.U");

panelbotones.add(botonfuel);
botonfuel.setText("Fuel Maestro");
botonfuel.setEnable(false);

panelbotones.add(botonstart);
botonstart.setText("Ignición");
botonstart.setEnable(false);

panelbotones.add(botonsiguiente);
botonsiguiente.setText("Siguiente");
botonsiguiente.setEnable(false); 

botonelectrico.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        botonfuel.setEnable(true);
    }
});


botonfuel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        botonstart.setEnable(true);
    }
});


botonstart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       botonsiguiente.setEnable(true); 
    }
});


botonsiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Aviso_despegue aviso;
        aviso = new Aviso_despegue();
        //Cambiar JPanel
    }
});
```

Comment: ya mismo me pongo manos a la obra a ver si lo puedo hacer.

Comment: Ahora funcionó excelente, era muy buena idea la de desactivar los botones, lo único que no hice fue darle a cada boton un actionlistener, sólo porque ya me perdí, de tanto código basura que fui poniendo. se vé que necesito hacer lo mismo pero más eficiente, porque el código que me pasaste estaba mucho más limpio.

Comment: @berlot83 Ten en cuenta que lo tuyo no esta malo, pero más que nada fue un consejo, para llevar un orden y poder ver bien el codigo sin depender de condiciones como los `if` y `else`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @sioesi

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30421/tocar-jbutton-siguiente-pasar-a-otras-opciones-sin-salir-del-jpanel

Comment: Que buena respuesta ésta, ahora después de casi dos años la releo ya programando en Android y me doy cuenta que es casi lo mismo, estoy usando los eventos de la misma manera que en Swing. Gracias @sioesi