# Tocar JButton "siguiente" pasar a otras opciones sin salir del JPanel?

Tags: java

Una pregunta, si quiero tocar en el "botonsiguiente" de un JPanel, y que me aparezcan varias opciones distintas, pero sin abrir una ventana nueva, cómo puedo hacerlo?
Mi programita se trata de varios problemas a resolver, ya realicé el primero, sin embargo cuando toco siguiente sólo sé como abrir un nuevo JPanel, nó cambiar la info del que está adentro, me siento muy cómodo trabajando por objetos creando un JPanel por cada problema, lo que no sé es como unirlos en el típico boton "siguiente".

Comment: Si quieres que multiples elementos se carguen en un mismo JPanel debes crear todos los eventos en la misma clase, OCULTAR los que estaban visibles y MOSTRAR los nuevos.... pero es preferible que cierres el JPanel completo y montes uno nuevo!

Comment: No se, si utilicé bien la palabra, se entendio que hablaba de la ventana no? porque puse Jpanel, pero quize decir JFrame, seguir en la misma ventana. si vos decis que es mucho bardo te hago caso y creo nuevas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberias ocultar el JPanel actual y hacer visible el otro panel para que te aparezcan las otras funciones que quieres sin crear otra pantalla o JFrame.